Polars does not seem to convert f64 to Integer, no errors thrown either
I have a column in a Polars dataframe that only has 1.0 and 0.0 values in it and there are no NaN values either.  I have tried the following method to cast this column from float64 to UInt8 (I tried other data types too) but none take and there is no error produced.  By does not take, I mean when I look at what describe() displays after the cast it shows the column still being float64.  Am I missing something?
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('target_class').cast(pl.UInt8))


Please post the full code. This works for me: pl.DataFrame({'foo': [1.0, 0.0]}).with_columns(pl.col("foo").cast(pl.UInt8)).

actually, I think it works....I just noticed that when I look at the output of df.describe it shows that the column is in fact Integer however I was using df.describe() to inspect which continues to show it as float64.  I don't know why or which I should be using when....   Maybe I should be using .glimpse to inspect column data types.

If you are just after the types of columns, DataFrame.schema or printing the DataFrame are the two best and simplest options. As you state, DataFrame.dtypes is another option, but means you have to know what order your columns are in (as the types are in that order).
DataFrame.describe(), prints summary stats, which is likely to be a floating point output for integer inputs.
# integer input, but float output required to represent mean and std.
print(pl.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1]}).describe())
┌────────────┬──────────┐
│ describe   ┆ a        │
│ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ str        ┆ f64      │
╞════════════╪══════════╡
│ count      ┆ 2.0      │
│ null_count ┆ 0.0      │
│ mean       ┆ 0.5      │
│ std        ┆ 0.707107 │
│ …          ┆ …        │
│ 75%        ┆ 1.0      │
│ max        ┆ 1.0      │
└────────────┴──────────┘

Also, describe, like everything else on the DataFrame class except for the attributes documented here, is a method, so you must call it as .describe() to use it.
Not calling it will likely give you something like this, which tells you it is a method (that needs to be called to be used), and then prints the DataFrame. That is why .describe is telling you the type was integer (because it is).
print(pl.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1]}).describe)
<bound method DataFrame.describe of shape: (2, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
└─────┘>


Code to cast column from float64 to UInt8 was correct, the issues was that I was using an incorrect method to validate the cast change was in fact made.  describe/describe() are not the correct methods to use, but instead both DataFrame.glimpse and better yet DataFrame.dtypes can be used to better inspect a dataframe data types.  Apologies...shows how new I am to this amazing Polars package.
